# What is the best practice to resize game views-assets in WPF/silverlight?

Tags: game-design, wpf, silverlight

I am working on simple game using WPF/C#, and I am wondering what is the best practice to resize the game (views, assets…) when user re-sizes the game window? Is it good practice to use the ViewBox control for this job?

Comment: Could you add some information about how your assets are currently represented and handled?

Comment: @josh The assets are very simple, user controls contain star-shape(s) with some animations –using storyboards- and I use canvas to contain these assets, during the game-play the assets move inside the canvas and do some actions/animations. Also, and as usual, I have other canvas for game option and game score and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the size you designed you application at and what resolutions you want to support, I've played with using a **ScaleTransform** to try getting my 800x600 app down to a smaller size for the windows phone 7 (I ran into other problems while converting my silverlight app to the windows phone 7 sdk so I gave up, but the scaling worked pretty nicely).

Mike Snow has a very good article on how to do this along with hooking up to the Content_Resized event in your Page:
[Silverlight Tip of the Day #33: How to Scale your entire App and its Elements to your Browsers Size](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/08/26/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-33-how-to-scale-your-entire-app-and-its-elements-to-your-browsers-size.aspx)

You do want to be careful since scaling your app down too small will make certain elements like text too small to read and unusable.